# Unable to set values dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to fetch the value of an input box and displaying that value dynamically using jquery .
The code works fine and loads the image on the check id.
But the value of user_id is not being displayed on `<p>`

The code is as follows :

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="user_id" id="user_id" class="user_name" >
            <button>Check</button>
    <span class="check"  ></span> <br/>
    <p> </p>


$(document).ready(function(){

  $("button").click(function(){
      $('.check').show();
      $('.check').fadeIn(400).html('<img src="image/ajax-loader.gif" /> ');

    var us=("#user_id").val();
    $("p").text(us);         


  });
});
```

Comment: Always check your console for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `$` sing:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $('.check').show();
  $('.check').fadeIn(400).html('<img src="image/ajax-loader.gif" /> ');
  var us= $("#user_id").val();
  $("p").text(us);            
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcxAw/)

Comment: hahaha damn it! I was looking and didn't notice that.. :D +1

Comment: oh..
I was stuck for around 25 mins for that :( Thanks

Comment: @ashwinbhy: Glad to help you( you could accept my answer as a correct answer). Your welcome :)